# Creating a Multi-Step FILTER Dynamic Array Function in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, filter, excel-formula, dynamic

I have a spreadsheet with five January entries and five February entries.

Column A:  Date
Column B:  Sales Person's Name
Column C:  Sales Person's Sales Amount for the month

| Date | Sales Person's Name | Sales Person's Sales Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/31/2023 | Ann | 500 |
| 1/31/2023 | Bill | 200 |
| 1/31/2023 | Tim | 100 |
| 1/31/2023 | Lee | 400 |
| 1/31/2023 | Bob | 300 |
| 2/28/2023 | Ann | 40 |
| 2/28/2023 | Bill | 20 |
| 2/28/2023 | Tim | 10 |
| 2/28/2023 | Lee | 30 |
| 2/28/2023 | Bob | 50 |

Desired Result (not sorted in any particular order):
Bob
Ann
Lee

I would like to display the three people with the highest sales for the most recent month with the expectation that I would be appending new month's data as it becomes available.

I tried using the below FILTER Dynamic Array formula but noticed that my criteria are mutually exclusive since the three largest values are in January but I am forcing it to look only at February data.

```
=FILTER(B2:B100,A2:A100=MAX(A2:A100)*(C2:C100=LARGE(C2:C100,3)))
```

I believe that I need to perform a multi-step FILTER but am unsure if this is possible in a single equation.  The first step would for the FILTER to include only the most recent month, and the second step would be to filter on the three largest sales figures.

Are there any suggestions on a non-VBA solution?

Comment: Try using this : `=CHOOSECOLS(TAKE(SORT(Salestbl,{1,3},{-1,-1}),3),2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the following formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=CHOOSECOLS(TAKE(SORT(Salestbl,{1,3},{-1,-1}),3),2)
```

---

- The above formula first sorts the date in descending order,
- Next, it sorts the sales price in the same above order,
- And takes the first 3 people with the highest sales.
- lastly extracting only the names of the sales person.

---

Test Case:

[image]

---

Or, do it as commented by **[JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv)** Sir.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>E2</kbd>

```
=TAKE(SORTBY(Salestbl[Sales Person''s Name],Salestbl[Date],-1,Salestbl[Sales Person''s Sales Amount],-1),3)
```

---

The above formula is basically as given by Sir

```
=TAKE(SORTBY(B2:B11,A2:A11,-1,C2:C11,-1),3)
```

---

I have used `Structured References` aka `Tables` so when you add the new data it picks up the data ranges automatically.

---

Comment: `=TAKE(SORTBY(B2:B11,A2:A11,-1,C2:C11,-1),3)`

Comment: Oh WOW @JvdV Sir Thank you very much sir again!

Comment: Thank you both for you comments and assistance.  Both approaches worked, and I learned from each.  One thing common in each approach was the use of the TAKE function.  I wasn't aware of it, but will add it to my tool chest.

Comment: @John63 there is one more function you need to see it is called **[DROP()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/drop-function-1cb4e151-9e17-4838-abe5-9ba48d8c6a34)** sharing since you are not aware also there are few more which you should take a look at here is a complete list **[New_Functions](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-new-text-and-array-functions/ba-p/3186066)**

Comment: @mayukh-bhattacharya - Thanks for the additional information!  I've been using several of the new functions in the link you mention, but I hadn't focused on the array manipulation formulas enough.

Comment: @John63 no worries. You can check some of the answers of mine as well JvdV Sir, it might help you more, to learn and it has helped me as well, by following JvdV Sirs answers